# How to configure assembler (@binutils) to be "noreorder" by default?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips, cross-compiling

I'm going to install an assembler which does not reorder instructions by default. I don't want to add ".set noreorder" in my assembly source code.

I think this can be done, because someone gave me his binary generated from the same assembly souece code. I compared it with mine, and found the only difference is the program header:

His:

```
private flags = 70003000: [abi=EABI32] [mips32r2] [not 32bitmode]
```

Mine:

```
private flags = 70003001: [abi=EABI32] [mips32r2] [not 32bitmode] [noreorder]
```

And if I remove ".set noreorder" in my assembly source code, my binary will be completely different from his.

So I think this is only because his assembler does not reorder instructions by default. But he doesn't know how to configure it because it is someone else that installed the assembler. Could anyone help me?